# NSTimer for UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, nstimer

I have a question about using NSTimer in combination with a label. I have not been able to find the answer to this yet, but this is probably elementary. I am still learning iOS...

My app is a calculator that contains a "Mode" button. By default, my calculator starts in Mode 1 with the label "messageText" stating "No Errors." When the mode button is pressed, I would like UILabel "messageText" to display the text "Mode 2" for 3 seconds, before it changes back to "No Errors."

I am not sure how to integrate the NSTimer with my label. Here is what I have so far. My problem is that **the variable *timer is unused**. How do I use this in conjunction with only my messageText label, and not the others? Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
-(IBAction)mode
{
years.text = @"0";
months.text = @"0";
days.text = @"0";

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target: self selector:@selector(timerEnded) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
messageText.text = @"Mode 2";

}

-(void)timerEnded
{
    messageText.text = @"No Errors";
}
```

Comment: @Anton Code should compile clean (no warnings). Most warnings are probably errors and the code should be fixed. Once you train yourself to ignore a warning, you start ignoring ones you shouldn't.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree with that, but I was under the impression that there was some kind of functionality error that OP is asking for help on since they mention the conjunction of a label and timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare and initialize a variable named `timer` but you never use it.

To eliminate the warning either use the variable elsewhere or don't create the variable. Just do:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target: self selector:@selector(timerEnded) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

If you might ever need to invalidate (stop) the timer, you should keep a reference in an ivar so you can call `invalidate` on it.

Comment: Thanks, now I better understand how to use NSTimer. It's working great.